# 'Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference' after adding a new value to Application Settings

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.7.2

If I add a new settings to my application Settings (VB.NET,NET 4.7.2), I got 142 errors:

> BC30469 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

on every code that uses `My.Settings`

If I use notepad++ and manually add the new value to `Settings.Designer.vb` and `Settings.settings`,there is no error

That worked fine, I think the problem is form recent VS 2022 updates

Settings.Designer.vb:

```vb
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' <auto-generated>
    '     This code was generated by a tool.
    '     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
    '
    '     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    '     the code is regenerated.
    ' </auto-generated>
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Option Strict On
    Option Explicit On

    Namespace My
        
        <Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute(),  _
         Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "17.6.0.0"),  _
         Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(Global.System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)>  _
        Partial Friend NotInheritable Class Settings
            Inherits Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase
            
            Private Shared defaultInstance As Settings = CType(Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(New Settings()),Settings)
    ....        
    
        <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.HideModuleNameAttribute(),  _
         Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
         Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()>  _
        Friend Module MySettingsProperty
            
            <Global.System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("My.Settings")>  _
            Friend ReadOnly Property Settings() As Global.Application.My.Settings
                Get
                    Return Global.Application.My.Settings.Default
                End Get
            End Property
        End Module
    End Namespace
```

Settings.settings :

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="Server_Name" Type="System.String" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">localhost</Value>
      ...
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```